# Configuration - > Zones admin page missing?

Tags: commerce

I've installed Drupal Commerce 2 and as explained here:

https://drupal-commerce.readthedocs.io/en/latest/v2/building-blocks/address/zones.html

there should be a "Zones" admin page at Configuration -> Zones. But I don't have that page and I only have "default" zone?!?

Only relevant module I found is:
https://www.drupal.org/project/address_zone

but it exists only for Drupal 7?!

What I'm trying actually is to configure Commerce Product Tax, which exists only for D8 and at screenshot from module page:
https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_product_tax

... they do have zones "France" and "France (Corsica)", so this should be possible somehow I guess.

How to administrate those zones and why I don't have that page under "Configuration" in my back-end?

Comment: Those docs are outdated, for Address [it shows this](https://drupal-commerce.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_images/address-configure.png) but its not there either. [Once upon a time, it existed](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/issues/2352711) tho so I suspect it's the same for zones, it later got removed/replaced.

Comment: Those are not the official Commerce docs, looks like a mirror that's many years out of date. The official docs are at https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the European Union VAT

[image]

As it has France and France (Corsica)

[image]